# Visual Basic | Replace Substring in String with String

Tags: vb.net, string, search, replace

Using Visual Basic, I want to replace a text within a String with another String. I do not know the location of this text within the String. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: any examples of what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
X = X.Replace("original"," toReplace")
```

[Or this link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace-vbnet):

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
    ' Input string.
    Dim input As String = "Dot Net Not Perls"
    ' Use Regex.Replace with string arguments.
    Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(input, "N.t", "NET")
    ' Print.
    Console.WriteLine(input)
    Console.WriteLine(output)
    End Sub
End Module

Output

Dot Net Not Perls
Dot NET NET Perls
```

Answer (score -1):

The replace method does not require you to know the location. You specify the original value, the string to look for, and the string to change it too. Very straight forward.

```
Dim aString As String = Replace("String to Search", "String to Find", "String to Replace With")
```

Comment: Except that’s not how you use it, you’re missing a quote, and that’s not how you declare variables in VB.NET.

Comment: I pulled from Visual Basic. I apologize if the syntax is different in VB.net http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: You said “method“, not “horrible VB6 legacy function”

Comment: Yeah but you still have the wrong formatting.

Comment: True and true.. was trying to be overly quick. I'll slow down in the future.

Comment: You *can* edit your answer, if you like! (It might also convince people to change votes)

Comment: Questions guys (new at commenting), if I provide something incorrect or missing something and it gets commented or down graded... should I leave it as-is so it's apparent as to why, or should I delete the comment entirely, or fix the error?

Comment: Gotcha, thanks minitech

Comment: Code has been corrected

Comment: @GaryRichter: If you provide something incorrect because of syntax/typos, feel free to edit it. If it’s totally incorrect, you can still edit it, but maybe making a new answer is more appropriate. If somebody else has already answered a significantly different “right thing” before you fix your answer, it might be best to delete it unless you can add more depth. And thanks for notfying :)